# Class not found in live server while nothing wrong in localhost

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel latest version, I have build a relation with User and Division models

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\User', 'id');
}

public function division() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Division', 'division_id');
}
```

And in blade view

```
<tr>
    <td class="">Division</td>
    <td class="">:</td>
    <td class="">{{ Auth::user()->division == null ? 'Not define' : Auth::user()->division->name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Local server is working fine, but in live server showing error

> Class App\models\Unioun not found

Comment: where you using`Unioun` .? put that code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your localhost runs on a windows machine which filesystem is case insensitive. So the application runs without any problem in case of case sensitivity. But live servers are mostly powered by Linux based OS which are case sensitive. Thus your `models` folder is not working as the folder name is `Models` as of laravel 8. Change like

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'id');
}

public function division() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Division', 'division_id');
}
```

Moreover you need not define the full namespace in case both the files in the same namespace. You can do just

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
}
```

However I am not certain why you are using `id` as the foreign key in user relationship. `id` should be `user_id`.

Comment: it will fix this `Class 'App\models\Unioun' not found` error .?

Comment: when i started adding the answer there was not that error message. i can see it after you edited the question. however op does not added anything related to the `Unioun` class. but i am certain case sensitivity is causing the issue here. peace :)